# Splitting a string into chunks of a certain nth sizes

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I had a string:

```
string str = "12386541";
```

How can I break this string into chunks of some size?

12

```
38

6541
```

i want to split first two then after next two then next four

Comment: Have you tried anything with `String.Substring()` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Have a look at the LINQ Take and Skip methods

Comment: no i didnt try String.Substring()  how should i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
string t1 = str.Substring(0, 2);
string t2 = str.Substring(2, 2);
string t3 = str.Substring(4, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the documentation for `string.Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you wanted a general purpose method to split a string into chunks, you could write it using `string.Substring()`.

Here's an example:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoChunks(string s, params int[] lengths)
{
    int start = 0;

    foreach (var length in lengths)
    {
        if (start >= s.Length)
            yield return "";
        else if ((start + length) >= s.Length)
            yield return s.Substring(start);
        else
            yield return s.Substring(start, length);

        start += length;
    }
}
```

Compilable console app to demonstrate its use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "12386541";
            var chunks = SplitIntoChunks(str, 2, 2, 4);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", chunks));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoChunks(string s, params int[] lengths)
        {
            int start = 0;

            foreach (var length in lengths)
            {
                if (start >= s.Length)
                    yield return "";
                else if ((start + length) >= s.Length)
                    yield return s.Substring(start);
                else
                    yield return s.Substring(start, length);

                start += length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth considering making this an extension-method.